# How to call java API from Lua Script using LuaJava

Tags: lua, luajava

I have one java program written but because of the application issues I can not call it directly, instead I can use Lua script. Can anyone please help me and guide me that is it possible to call that Java program fro the Lua script. I am very new to Lua Scripting and a basic beginner for LuaJava.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [calling Java program from Lua script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246064/calling-java-program-from-lua-script). Not getting an answer for your question is not a legitimate reason to repost it.

Comment: ^ Link has been removed